# Класс - матрица со случайными значениями

Tags: c++, классы, случайные-числа, матрицы, динамические-массивы

Цель - создать класс матрица, который бы умел создавать двумерные массивы заданных размеров, но со случайными значениями. 
Массив создаётся, но значения я получаю каждый раз одинаковые. Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чём проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:

int str;
int col;
int **mat;
public:
Matrix(int str, int col)      //конструктор класса
{
    this -> str = str;
    this -> col = col;
    mat = new int*[str];
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new int[col];
    }
    cout << "Конструктор " << this << endl;

}   

void FillMatrix()     //метод заполнения
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j] = rand() %10;
        }
    }
}

void PrintMatrix()       //вывод
{

    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << mat[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

~Matrix()        //деструктор, я его должен дописать. 
{
delete[]mat;
        cout << "Destruct" << this << endl << endl;
}


};

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

Matrix a(3, 3);
Matrix b(3, 3);


b.FillMatrix();
a.FillMatrix();

a.PrintMatrix();
b.PrintMatrix();
}
```

Comment: `srand` нужно вынести из цикла, например перениести в `main`. Звать `srand` нужно один раз. Время при вызове `srand` не меняется, возможно на очень медленной машине результаты этой программы будут лучше)))

Comment: @nick_n_a Благодарствую за ответ, всё получилось! Предполагал, что что-то с `srand` не так, потому что адреса массивов разные получались, но не знал, где она точно должна лежать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Отсюда](http://cppstudio.com/post/841/):

> Для любого другого значения, передаваемого через параметр  `seed`, и
>   используемого при вызове функции `srand`, алгоритм генерации
>   псевдо-случайных чисел может генерировать различные числа с каждым
>   последующим вызовом функции `rand`. Если использовать одно и то же
>   значение `seed`, с каждым вызовом функции `rand`, алгоритм генерации
>   псевдо-случайных чисел будет генерировать ту же самую
>   последовательность чисел.

Я бы делал так:

```
#include <random>

class Matrix
{
private:
    std::mt19937 random_generator_;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> rand_uid(0, 9);
public:
    Matrix()      //конструктор класса
    {
        std::random_device random_device;
        random_generator_.seed(random_device()); 
    }   

    void FillMatrix()     //метод заполнения
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                mat[i][j] = rand_uid(random_generator_));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Это тоже ГПСЧ ведь. Из библиотеки Windows.h использую генерацию, говорят криптографически сильная, да и на практике подтверждается.

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно изучу! Я пока только классы изучаю, до разных библиотек не дошёл - будет поводом)